# pyinstaller on UBuntu , giving error "pyconfig.h not found"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, pyinstaller

[image]

I am trying to convert my python script to executable file on ubuntu in virtual environmentn using pyinstaller. But its giving error saying "/python2.7/pyconfig.h" when adding binary and data files".... I have attached the screenshot here.

So far whatever I have tried to resolve this are :

1. sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
2. Even added empty "pyconfig.h" file to /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils or to virtualenv folder i.e /home/infinite-uptime/ammu_env/local/lib/python2.7

but couldn't get it fixed.
Any Idea please ? Thanks